# Posts where facebook page is tagged

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've built a photo gallery on my website where I'm showing photos from one of the Facebook pages and it's summary (no of likes, comments, shares etc). Everything works just fine.

After that, I extended my solution and allow users to tag my pages on the photos. For this I followed the steps below:

1. Get access token of the person with **manage_pages** permissions.
2. Get a facebook page access token Page Access Tokens menu.
3. called `me/tagged` or `/page-id/tagged` to get the posts where the page is tagged.

Following API reference I used while developing the solution.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/tagged
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed

> If you want the app to be able to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this feature for review.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get all of the posts, photos where my page is tagged in. But, I'm getting only the posts which users posts on my page wall and tagged me. I researched it and found that `Page Public Content Access` permission is required and it specifies this in the description

In my understanding, either I'm missing some part of permission or understanding it in a wrong way. I'm using v3.1 of the graph API.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

**Edit**

Based on the misorude's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52217409/1926877), I've done the following steps
I've two accounts say A and B.

From Account A:

1. Created a new app from the account A.
2. Get access token of the person
3. with manage_pages permissions.
4. Made another user B admin of the app.

From Account B:

1. Accept admin invitation for the app.
2. Get Access Token from the app with user_posts.
3. Added a picture, tagged page and post it.

Now again, goes to graph API explorer and invoked `me/tagged` using page access token, still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Page Public Content Access would only get you access to post made on other pages, you won’t get posts made on user profiles with that.

Posts on user profiles would only be available to your app, if the user that made the post has logged in to your app and granted it `user_posts` permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the question and did a small test based on your reply.

Comment: Was that user post public? If it was and still didn’t work, it might be that you just can’t get posts where users tagged your page at all any more. The documentation mentions conditions for tags by other pages, but doesn’t say anything specifically about user posts. But with the latest changes, they might have simply removed that.

Comment: yes, the post was public. I specifically checked it. So, it means I've to ask from facebook help.